# Show that $|A+A|\geq (2n-1)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality, additive-combinatorics, sumset

> **Consider a set $A$ consisting of $n$ natural numbers $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^n$ such that $a_1<a_2 < \cdots <a_{n-1} < a_n$. Define the set $A+A$ such that it contains $a_i + a_j \ ; \ i \leq j$ as its elements.**
>
> **Prove That $|A+A| \geq (2n-1)$. When does the equality hold?**

I tried to list out the elements for general $n$, but it became too tedious.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, the equality holds iff $A$ is an arithmetic progression.  This result probably generalizes for any arbitrary field, not just $\mathbb{R}$, where you have an ordering compatible with addition, which is required in Michael Burr's hint.

Comment: I meant "any arbitrary field of characteristic zero," as this claim is most likely false for nonprime finite fields, even when $A$ is a small set.

Comment: @Batominovski I gauge that you know quite a lot about this problem. Can you please post a solution explaining the details?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey What is this CMI? I heard that for my last question as well. I've got this in a worksheet given to me by my teacher.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey My teacher gave me a "worksheet" not a book. I'll have to ask him where did he get the problem from.

Comment: @Batominovski there is no actual multiplication in this result. A convenient general context are torsion-free abelian groups (which are precisely those abelain groups that admit a total order).

Comment: @quid  How do you prove that every torsion-free abelian group admits a total order compatible with the addition?  (Although to prove your version, it does not require to deal with the order for the whole group, just that of a finitely generated subgroup, which is free of finite rank, whence equipped with such an order.)

By the way, the result can even be more generalized than that, if I remember correctly.  If $(G,\cdot)$ is a group such that every non-identity element does not have a finite order, then $|A\cdot B|\geq |A|+|B|-1$ for any nonempty finite subsets $A$ and $B$ of $G$.

Comment: @Batominovski consider it as subset of its divisible hull, which is  $\mathbb{Q}^{(I)}$ for some cardinal, and order that, say, lexicographically. [Disclaimer: this works in "usual" foundations, I am not sure if there is some issue if you do not have "choice" or some such thing.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $A$ and $B$ are finite nonempty subsets of an integral domain $D$ of characteristic $0$, whose field of fractions is $F$.  We claim that $|A+B|\geq |A|+|B|-1$, and that the equality holds iff $A$ and $B$ are arithmetic progressions with the same common difference.  (If $A$ and $B$ are arithmetic progressions with the same common difference, then it is easily seen that the equality occurs.)

First, note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subfield of $F$, and the smallest subfield $K$ of $F$ containing $A$ and $B$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with finite transcendental degree.  Hence, $K$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{C}$.  Therefore, it suffices to prove the claim when $D=F=\mathbb{C}$.

Now, we equip $\mathbb{C}$ with the total ordering $<$ by demanding that, for $x,x',y,y'\in\mathbb{R}$, $x+\text{i}y<x'+\text{i}y'$ iff (1) $x<x'$ or (2) $x=x'$ and $y<y'$.  This ordering is compatible with addition, namely, for $z_1,z_2,z\in\mathbb{C}$, $z_1<z_2$ implies $z_1+z<z_2+z$.

Write $A=\left\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m\right\}$ and $B=\left\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_n\right\}$ such that $a_1<a_2<\ldots<a_m$ and $b_1<b_2<\ldots<b_n$ (making $m=|A|$ and $n=|B|$).  Without loss of generality, assume that $m\leq n$.  Then, $$a_1+b_1<a_1+b_2<\ldots<a_1+b_n<a_2+b_n<\ldots<a_m+b_n\,.\tag{*}$$
This proves that $A+B$ has at least $m+n-1=|A|+|B|-1$ elements.

Suppose that the equality $|A+B|=|A|+|B|-1$ holds.  Note that
$$a_1+b_1<a_2+b_1<\ldots<a_m+b_1<a_m+b_2<\ldots<a_m+b_n\tag{**}$$
also contains $m+n-1$ elements of $A+B$.  We conclude that $a_1+b_i=a_i+b_1$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,m$.  Thus, $b_i=a_i+t$, where $t:=b_1-a_1$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,m$. Since $$a_1+b_1<a_1+b_2<a_2+b_2<a_3+b_2<\ldots<a_m+b_2<a_m+b_3<\ldots<a_m+b_n$$
also contains $2+(m-1)+(n-2)=m+n-1$ elements of $A+B$, we have that $a_2+b_2=a_1+b_3$, $a_3+b_2=a_1+b_4$, $\ldots$, $a_{m-1}+b_2=a_1+b_m$.  Thus, $$a_2-a_1=b_3-b_2=(a_3+t)-(a_2+t)=a_3-a_2\,,$$ 
$$a_3-a_1=b_4-b_2=(a_4+t)-(a_2+t)=a_4-a_2\,,$$
$$\ldots\,,$$ 
$$a_{m-1}-a_1=b_m-b_2=(a_m+t)-(a_2+t)=a_m-a_2\,.$$
This proves that $a_2-a_1=a_3-a_2=\ldots=a_m-a_{m-1}=:d$.  That is, $A$ is an arithmetic progression with common difference $d$.

From the relationship between $a_i$ and $b_i$ with $i=1,2,\ldots,m$, we conclude that $\left\{b_1,b_2,\ldots,b_m\right\}$ is a subset of $B$ which is an arithmetic progression with common difference $d$.  Now, from (*) and (**), $a_1+b_{m+1}=a_m+b_2$, $a_1+b_{m+2}=a_m+b_3$, $\ldots$, $a_1+b_n=a_m+b_{n+1-m}$.  This implies that $$b_{m+1}=b_2+(a_m-a_1)=b_m+d\,,$$ $$b_{m+2}=b_3+(a_m-a_1)=b_{m+1}+d\,,$$ $$\ldots\,,$$ $$b_n=b_{n+1-m}-(a_m-a_1)=b_{n-1}+d\,.$$  Thus, $B$ is an arithmetic progression with common difference $d$ as well.

Note that, if $D$ is the field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for a prime natural number $p$, then we have a similar inequality, known as the Cauchy-Davenport Inequality: $|A+B|\geq \min\big\{p,|A|+|B|-1\big\}$.  This last inequality is also true in general for an integral domain $D$ of characteristic $p$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Why are 
$$
a_n+a_n,a_n+a_{n+1},\cdots,a_n+a_2,a_n+a_1,a_{n-1}+a_1,\cdots,a_2+a_1,a_1+a_1
$$
all distinct?

To see that this is the minimum, suppose that $A$ is an arithmetic sequence:
$$
A=\{a_1,a_1+r,a_1+2r,\cdots,a_1+(n-1)r\}.
$$
Then the list above is $\{2a_1,2a_1+r,\cdots,2a_1+2(n-1)r\}$.  Can you prove that every $a_i+a_j$ is in this list?

Comment: They are distinct, but can you show that this is the minimum?

Comment: Showing that $2n-1$ is the minimum is not the same as answering the question "When does the equality hold?"

Comment: @Batominovski Can you provide a complete solution? Thanks!

Comment: Not right now.  Typing this on an iPad is too much work.  But it is not too difficult.  Maybe, somebody will post the solution before I have access to better computers.  My first hint is: what should the value of $a_2+a_2$ be if the minimum is achieved?

Answer (score 1):

if $A=\{ 1,...,n\}$, then $A+A=\{2,...,2n\}$. A simple computation gives that $|A|=n$ and $|A+A|=2n-1$.

Following the hint of Michael Burr, $a_n+A\cap a_1+A=\{ a_1+a_n \}$. Therefore, using the classical formula $card(A\cup B)=card(A)+card(B)-card(A\cap B)$, we have that $card(A+A)\geqslant card(\{ a_1,a_n\} + A)=card(a_1+A\cup a_n+A) = 2n-1$.

Comment: Can you please explain the notation used in the first line?

Comment: Do you mean $card$ ? It is the number of element in a set. With your notations, $card(A)$ is $|A|$. $card$ might be a french notation. Also, $[1;n]\cap \mathbb{N}$ is equal to $\{1,...,n\}$.

Comment: I know $card$, what do you mean by "if $A=[1;n]\cap \mathbb{N}$, then $A+A=[2;2n]\cap\mathbb{N}$" ?

Comment: I am using your notations here. $A+A=\{ a_i+a_j;1 \leqslant i,j\leqslant n\}=\{ i+j, 1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n\}$

Comment: Note that this proves that $2n-1$ is the minimum.

Comment: Can you edit the first line so that it is simple to read (using my notation)? Thanks.

Comment: You have just computed the cardinality for a special case when the elements are consecutive integers.